# kotlin generics for Consumer only

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, kotlin-generics

Let' say i have this java example:

```
interface Sink<T> {
    void accumulate(T t);
}

public static <T> void drainToSink(Collection<T> collection, Sink<? super T> sink) {
    collection.forEach(sink::accumulate);
}
```

Notice how the second parameter is declared to be `? super T`. I need this because I want to call that method like this:

```
Sink<Object> sink = .... // some Sink implementation
Collection<String> strings = List.of("abc");
drainToSink(strings, sink);
```

Now I am trying to achieve the same thing with kotlin (which I have very small experience with):

```
interface Sink<T> {
    fun accumulate(t: T)
}

fun <T> drainToSink(collection: List<T>, sink: Sink<T>) {
   ....
}
```

And now I am trying to use it:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

     val sink = object : Sink<Any> {
         override fun accumulate(any: Any) {  }
     }

     val strings = emptyList<String>()
     drainToSink(strings, sink)
}
```

Interestingly enough, this does not fail (unless I know too little about kotlin here).

I was really expecting that I need to add to the declaration something like `Sink<in T>` to let the compiler know that this is actually *just* a `Consumer`, or is `in T` always on, by default?

Can someone who knows kotlin better than me, point me in the right direction?

Comment: Isn't `T` just being inferred to `Any` here? And since you have [`List<out T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) that also works for the first parameter?

Comment: @JornVernee seems to be right - Kotlin's `List` is indeed [`List<out E>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html), as opposed to its [`MutableList<E>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html).

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski oh shoot! so that turns out to become `List<? extends T>` sort of... well sounds like an answer to me

Comment: @JornVernee you're right...

Comment: `Sink` should probably just be declared as `Sink<in T>`...

Comment: @LouisWasserman that is correct *in general*, my question was why *not* declaring it still makes it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, `T` is being inferred as `Any` here. That's what I see when letting my IDE add explicit type arguments to the `drainToSink` call.

Since kotlin's [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) is strictly a producer, because it is immutable, it declares it's type parameter as `out E`. You get `List<Any>` as a parameter type for `drainToSink`, and it's fine to assign a `List<String>` to that:

```
val strings = emptyList<String>()
val x: List<Any> = strings // works
```

If you change the first parameter type to `MutableList<T>`, which does not have a covariant type parameter, your example *does* fail:

```
fun <T> drainToSink(collection: MutableList<T>, sink: Sink<T>) {
    ....
}
```

```
val strings = emptyList<String>()
drainToSink(strings, sink) // type mismatch: Required: MutableList<Any>, Found: List<String>
```

Comment: well that is interesting, so in java words that method would become `public static <T> void drainToSink(List<? extends T> collection, Sink<T> sink) {` (because of that `out`), so yes I can see that `T` would be inferred to `Any`.

Comment: Now I have a problem understanding this `val strings = emptyList<String>()
val x: List<Any> = strings // works` or to be more exact what is the translation of this to java... well `emptyList` would be `List<? extends String>`, but what about `List<Any>`? `List<?>` or `List<? extends Object>`, because as far as I understand it can't be `List<Object>`...

Comment: @Eugene Yeah, you need a wildcard when translating `List<Any>` to Java. I guess technically it would become `List<? extends Any>`, but since Java doesn't have `Any`, the closest is probably `List<? extends Object>` which is more or less the same as `List<?>`. And indeed, `List<?> l = (List<? extends String>) new ArrayList<String>();` also works fine.

Comment: well if we "translate" `List<Any>` to `List<?>`, how would I translate `List<*>`? :) this is slightly eating my brain in mysterious ways

Comment: @Eugene Also to `List<?>` I'd say.